# adding days to dates bring up ValueError:Unconverted data remains

Tags: python, datetime

This is another probably very simple question, but I haven't been able to find anything to fix it so far.

I'm trying to add 14 days to some dates in a list of 2000 lists (each list is `['number1','number2','Day Month Year']`) and put the new date as a value at the end of each list (i.e. each list becomes `['number1', 'number2', 'Day Month Year', 'Day Month Year']`).
What I've got so far is:

```
from datetime import timedelta
listf=[]
z=range(len(hinfo))
for i in z:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(hinfo[i][2],'%d %b %y')
    listf.append(hinfo[i][2]+timedelta(days=14))
```

But this brings up the error 'ValueError: unconverted data remains: 01'. All of the dates in the list should be fine so I can't figure out why the errors coming up.
Forgive a beginner if it's just a simple mistake :)

Thanks!

Comment: Show some examples of your input data.

Comment: 'C148', 'W29', '08 August 2001' and 'Q964', 'R72', '21 May 2003', everything follows this pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code that appends the new date to the original list, as you specified in your question:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

hinfo = [['C148', 'W29', '08 August 2001'], ['Q964', 'R72', '21 May 2003']]

for i, h in enumerate(hinfo):
    if h[2] == '': # error checking
        del hinfo[i]
        continue
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(h[2], '%d %B %Y')
    d += timedelta(days=14)
    h.append(d.strftime('%d %B %Y'))

print hinfo
```

For me, this prints `[['C148', 'W29', '08 August 2001', '22 August 2001'], ['Q964', 'R72', '21 May 20
03', '04 June 2003']]`, which is what you wanted, if I understood your question correctly.

If you get an error, it is most likely that the input is not as you said, or think it is.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted :) But I'm still getting the ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d %B %Y' error. If I could figure out where it's coming from I might be able to fix it myself, I just don't know why it's coming up

Comment: It says 'time data', is it because it expects a time to be included too?

Comment: Clearly something isn't quite what you think it is, so add a try/except to catch the ValueError and print the data that's causing it to barf.

Comment: @Snaaa and @RodHyde The ValueError should already display the data and should be: `ValueError: time data '08 aug 2001' does not match format '%d %B %Y'`. Instead, it shows that the data is empty (the empty quotes in the middel of the error message). Snaaa, can you post the output of `repr(hinfo[:3])`, so that I can verify the format of your input?

Comment: print(repr(hinfo[:3])) makes [['A010', 'C1', '21 May 2001'], ['F108', 'C1', '27 July 2006'], ['E102', 'C1', '11 June 2005']] print maybe 100 times

Comment: Ok, it should have just printed the list of the three lists: `[['A010', 'C1', '21 May 2001'], ['F108', 'C1', '27 July 2006'], ['E102', 'C1', '11 June 2005']]` and nothing else. Could it be that `hinfo` is a list of lists of lists? You said that it printed that maybe 100 times, do you mean 100 times the same data, or 100 times the amount? Can you give the output of `len(hinfo)`, `len(hinfo[0])` and `repr(hinfo[0][:3])`?

Comment: hinfo is 1025 long, it should be a list of lists, not a list of lists of lists. Doing a try (x), except (print('nope')) has given me 6 nopes, if that helps

Comment: len(hinfo[0])=3
repr(hinfo[0][:3])=['A010', 'C1', '21 May 2001']

Comment: Yes, that helps! They are indeed lists of lists, and not lists of lists of lists. It seems that six dates are empty strings. I edited the code in my answer to check for these empty dates, could you tell me the output? (should be six lines)

Comment: 193
248
710
771
805
1230 pops out now

Comment: `['193', '', '', '']` `['248', '', '', '']`... I hope, otherwise something is very wrong

Comment: Well, turns out those lines are missing a date. I'll delete them, if I figure out how

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the results of strptime, though that isn't why you are getting the error from strptime.  The error is because you want %Y instead of %y.  You want something like this:

```
listf = []
for h in hinfo:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(h[2], "%d %b %Y")
    listf.append(d + timedelta(days=14))
```

%y is a two-digit year, %Y is a four-digit year.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's still bringing up the same ValueError though, but I think it's fixed another problem I was having

Comment: I changed it to %d %B %Y, but now it reckons 'ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d %B %Y''. Sorry if this is all due to my typos :/

Comment: I don't see why that would be.

Comment: Could it be a problem elsewhere in the code? I don't see how, but I can't see a problem here either